# How to record a audio in Android and save it in Database?

Tags: android, audio-recording

Hi
I am making an Android app for recording a audio for 5-10 sec and store that in Database.
For audio recording i follow this  http://xhampa.pastebin.com/Yr2hie6q

But it is not working properly. What to do ?
I can not record the Audio on my G1 mobile. 
Any suggestion welcome.

Comment: Klaus Byskov Hoffmann , When i am testing with my G1 mobile its not recording anything.

Comment: If you give us non-technical details, you will get a non-technical answer.  We can infer that your app is not recording anything by the mere existence of this question.  You need to provide technical details about what is not working, what the symptoms are, what logcat messages you see, etc.

Answer (score 1):

For your audio recording, try this code:

```
MediaRecorder recorder;

public void startRecording() throws IOException 
{
SimpleDateFormat timeStampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
        "yyyy-MM-dd-HH.mm.ss");
String fileName = "audio_" + timeStampFormat.format(new Date())
        + ".mp4";
recorder = new MediaRecorder();  
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); 
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP); 
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB); 
recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/"+fileName);
recorder.prepare(); 
recorder.start();
}

protected void stopRecording() {
recorder.stop();
recorder.release();
}
```

You can find your file on your sdcard.