# Android playback recorded audio

Tags: android, audiorecord

I've been looking at this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/8974361/1191501 and it works perfectly.  But my problem is how do I reference the recorded audio so it can be played back straight away?

the output code is:

```
recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/audio/"+filename);
```

and this definitely records the audio.

and then to playback the audio, I was using:

```
player.setDataSource();
```

but I don't know how to reference the filename bit so it plays back.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems playing audio from the SD card at one point.  This is what did it for me:

```
private void playMedia() {
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/audio_stuff.mp3";
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(path));
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Make sure to release your MediaPlayer instance and set it to null when you are done.  And just in case, make sure your SD card is not mounted when you try to play your audio file. :)

Comment: Yeah made sure mediaplayer was released and set to null, still nothing.  Just out of interested would I not need the SD card to be mounted in order to play the file, because that is where it is being stored?

Comment: By "mounted" I mean that you're device is connected to your computer via the the USB cable with access enabled to your SD card.

Comment: Ah ok, I'm not using a device at the moment, just the emulator.

Comment: I've tested on device and still same problem.  It won't play the file straight away, but will play it through the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Looking [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.lang.String%29),

```
player.setDataSource("/sdcard/audio/"+filename);
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

would work I would think.

Comment: I'm afraid not.  I'm just getting logcat error 04-13 03:26:29.180: E/MediaPlayer(7507): error (1, -2147483648) and its unable to read from sdcard.

Comment: Are you able to verify that the file is actually being written?

Comment: yes, I've set up a menu that shows audio on the sdcard and when selected, it loads into a player.  When I select the audio that has just been recorded, it plays no problem.  I'm just having a problem playing back the audio without having to go into the menu.